# Android:get a RSS tag content as a string

Tags: java, android, tags, rss

Hey i wish to take a tag from an RSS feed in this case the Lowest tag and turn the content inside this tag into a string. so for example

```
<Lowest>
11
</Lowest>
```

this would give me 11 as a string. How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what XML parser you're using for this. If you're using Android's XmlPullParser, you'll have to use parser.getText() once you reach that element.